# mod_rewrite doesn't work at all

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I have my small website (made for study purposes) on localhost and I am trying to get *.htaccess* working (note that I am a complete beginner to *.htaccess*). So far, I have discovered that *.htaccess* is not even read by the server (I tried creating a custom 404 page - no change).

I've got my server setup on a Raspberry Pi and I am accessing it over a local network. But even after allowing mod_rewrite using `sudo a2enmod rewrite` (and rebooting apache2) it still doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Ask for any additional info. I will do my best to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your .htaccess is not being read by the server, then that's the problem you need to fix first.  Enabling .htaccess files is done using the `AllowOverride` directive, which tells Apache to look for that file in the specified folder for additional configuration info.

If you're using the default vhost (which will be somewhere like `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`), then check that file for:

```
AllowOverride None
```

and change it to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

If it appears in that file multiple times, you only want to edit the one relating to your DOCUMENT_ROOT directory.

If the line isn't in there, check your main Apache config file instead.

If you've created a new vhost, you'll need to add a new `<Directory>` block:

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/docroot">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Alternatively, anything you put in a .htaccess file could instead be put in the vhost itself.